# Write Microsoft Forms data to Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to create a data entry form for my users, writing to an existing table in my Azure SQL Server.

At present I'm using Microsoft Forms, exporting the data as an Excel spreadsheet each week and manually loading this in to Azure SQL Server. Can this be achieved using Flow, or is there a better method for data entry forms on Azure?

Comment: Power Apps is the service for no-code forms. https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Flow. Microsoft Forms connector is available in the Logic Apps、Flow and PowerApps.
[image]

For more details, please reference: [Introducing the Microsoft Forms connector for Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-microsoft-forms-connector-for-flow/).

Here is a tutorial: [Building flows from scratch that handle Microsoft Forms responses](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/building-scratch-forms-responses/), It also says: you can route the response to your favorite database service or create a new record in Google Sheet or Excel.

Flow gives you the template: [Store Microsoft Forms responses in a SQL Server table](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/16d3143464064a248761d9ba54bcc7e8/store-microsoft-forms-responses-in-a-sql-server-table/):

When a response is submitted through Microsoft Forms, store the submitted form data in a SQL Server table. The table must have the columns: SubmittedBy and SubmitttedDtm.

Hope this helps.